# How to write custom shader for 3D meshes in WPF with custom vertex and texture properties?

Tags: wpf, 3d, shader, customization

I am pretty new to WPF and want to use the 3D rendering options in WPF. For this I need to write **custom shaders for my 3D meshes**. I searched a lot, but haven't found anything related to 3D. I only found the `ShaderEffect`, that can be used for 2D graphics. So is there any way to do this? Maybe by looking on how the `DiffuseMaterial` or other `Material` work?